# Twilio A2P. Add sender after registration

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Is it possible to add numbers after A2P registration.

Hello! I am registering A2P for my company and I am wondering if my numbers will also be added to A2P if I buy them after A2P registration. If not, please let me know if they can be added after registration, perhaps via API. I am not an ISV, I am a direct brand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add them individually to a Message Service after purchasing a new number. You can add them either using the REST API or the website Console.

> Any numbers that you add to that Messaging Service will be
> automatically associated with the approved Campaign. For help adding
> numbers to a Messaging Service, see [How Do I Add Numbers to a
> Messaging Service](https://help.twilio.com/articles/4402705042075-How-do-I-add-numbers-to-a-Messaging-Service-).  Not sure which numbers remain unregistered?